# Is this series well defined?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let's consider functional following:

$$f : l^2 \ni(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

I'm trying to prove or disprove fact - if this series well defined ?

Because $x_n \in l^2$, then:

$$\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+...} <\infty$$

I wasn't sure how to judge on definition of $f$. It's quite obvious when it's in $l^1$ - we just need to consider absolut convergence:

$$\sum_n |\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}| \le \sum_n|x_n| \;\;\;\; \text{And this would be convergent if $x_n \in l^1$}$$

However, we have $l^2$ space and I don't see how we can use this fact. Could you please give me a hand doing so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, let $x_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n \ln(n+1)}.$ Then $(x_n)\in l^2.$ But

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n+1)} = \infty.$$

Comment: (+1) I was just about to post the same answer.

Comment: I have a doubt. Doesn't your fact prove that $(\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{i}})_n \notin l^2 $? For just showing whether the series is well defined, all we have to show is that $\forall n \in N, \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{i}}$ is well defined - but as $n$ is finite, this must be true??

Comment: My interpretation was the OP was asking if $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}$$ necessarily converges.

Comment: Ah I see, so the series doesn't converge (as you showed), but the sequence of partial sums is still well defined.

Comment: @Kaind $f$ would be well-defined if we allowed $\infty$ as a value, but since that makes the question uninteresting (as you noticed), we assumed the question was about convergence.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: References for $\sum\frac1{n\ln^2(n+1)}<\infty$ and $\sum\frac1{n\ln(n+1)}=\infty$ would be appreciated!

Comment: @Karl Both results follow from the integral test.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you very much for your time!